# GAE Python: Process terminated because the backend was stopped

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have created a separate module within my application, with manual scaling and 1 instance, to loop through a Pull queue, leasing and completing tasks one at at time. In order for this to happen, I have a RequestHandler that is mapped to '/_ah/start' that registers a shutdown hook and starts a background thread. The background thread loops through the queue, leases a task, and uses that to parse a CSV file. So far, everything works okay, except for the shutdown hook. I don't think it ever runs. Here is my code:

```
class FileParserWrapper(object):

def __init__(self):

    version = os.getenv('CURRENT_VERSION_ID').split('.')
    if version[0] == 'test':
        self.instance = 'development'
    else:
        self.instance = 'production'

    if (os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE') and
        os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE').startswith('Google App Engine/')):
        if self.instance == 'development':
            self.staging_db = MySQLdb.connect(unix_socket='/cloudsql/' + _INSTANCE_NAME, db='xxxxxx', user='xxxxxx')
        else:
            self.staging_db = MySQLdb.connect(unix_socket='/cloudsql/' + _INSTANCE_NAME, db=STAGING_DB_NAME, user='xxxxxx')
    else:
        self.staging_db = MySQLdb.connect(host='xxxxxx', db='xxxxxx', user='xxxxxx')

    self.staging_cursor = self.staging_db.cursor()
    self.current_task = None
    self.current_state = 'inactive'
    self.current_task_complete = False
    self.last_task_complete = False
    self.retries = 0

def __enter__(self):

    return self

def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    logging.info('FileParserWrapper.__exit__()')

    self.staging_cursor.close()
    if self.staging_db.open:
        self.staging_db.close()


def shutdown(self):
    logging.info('FileParserWrapper.shutdown()')
    apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.CancelApiCalls()
    # save_state()
    self.__exit__(None, None, None)
    # May want to raise an exception


def generate_payload_dict(self, p):
    ...


def reset_tables(self, upload_id, format):
    ...


def run_parser(self):

    if self.instance == 'development':
        q = taskqueue.Queue('test-queue')
    else:
        q = taskqueue.Queue('ir-upload-queue')

    t = q.lease_tasks(3600, 1)
    while t:

        self.current_state = 'active'
        self.current_task = t[0].name
        payload = self.generate_payload_dict(t[0].payload)

        logging.info('***  Processing task ' + self.current_task + '  ***')
        logging.debug(repr(payload))

        with FileParser() as fp:

            try:
                logging.info('Beginning parse...')
                result = fp.ParseFile(payload['new_file_name_full'], payload['format'], payload['upload_id'], payload)
                if payload['name_file_temp'] != None and result == True:
                    fp.ParseFile(payload['new_csu_name_file_name_full'], "name", payload['upload_id'], payload)

            except:
                logging.error('Unknown error occured!')
                self.last_task_complete = False
                # Release the task lease
                q.modify_task_lease(t[0], 0)
                self.reset_tables(payload['upload_id'], payload['format'])
                raise

            else:
                self.last_task_complete = True
                q.delete_tasks_by_name(self.current_task)

        if self.last_task_complete == True:
            # Sleep for 5 seconds, then check for new tasks
            time.sleep(5)
            t = q.lease_tasks(3600, 1)

    logging.info('Loop complete, shutting down')
    # Shutdown the instance
    modules.stop_version()



class BatchProcessorHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

def get(self):

    proc = FileParserWrapper()

    def run(arg):
        proc.run_parser()

    def shutdown():
        logging.info('BatchProcessorHandler().get().shutdown()')
        self.response.set_status(200)
        proc.shutdown()

    # Register shutdown hook
    hook = runtime.set_shutdown_hook(shutdown)
    # Start background thread
    tid = background_thread.start_new_background_thread(run, [True])


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/_ah/start', BatchProcessorHandler),
], debug=True)
```

As you can see, I placed log messages in every method that should be called when the shutdown hook is processed, but I never see them in the logs. I either see requests to "/_ah/start" and "/_ah/background", or I see requests to "/_ah/start", "/_ah/background", and "/_ah/stop". In the latter version, "/_ah/stop" receives a HTTP 500 code, and the last message in the log is "Process terminated because the backend was stopped". This behavior seems to occur at random, and there is very few posts on Google which mention this particular error message.

Why is this behavior occurring? I have combed through the Google App Engine code locally and could not find this message. The code also states that the Runtime API and Background Threads are deprecated, even though the documentation for Modules, which replaces Backends, has code samples that use this very same code. Could the `runtime.set_shutdown_hook` function be bugged?

** some code has been omitted for readability

Comment: Same issue here. Have you found a solution? After short investigation I figured out this happens when we do deploy. Works like a charm if you simple turn the instance off from GAE panel but it's still a problem for us.

Answer (score 1):

So this isn't a direct answer, but it was how I solved this problem:

I switched from manual scaling to basic scaling.

Once I switched to basic scaling, the shutdown hook ran perfectly, but you don't call it directly. With basic scaling, the server handles the shutdown itself, and you just set a variable (idle-timeout I think) in the YAML file for your module. I set mine to 5 minutes, which works for my project. I had to shift some of the RequestHandlers around to make sure everything was getting called correctly. Here is my current code:

**YAML file**

```
application: xxxxxxxxx
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
module: batch-processor
instance_class: B4_1G
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
  idle_timeout: 5m
```

**Python (abridged)**

```
class FileParserWrapper(object):
    ...

    def run_parser(self):

        self.current_state = 'active'

        if self.instance == 'development':
            q = taskqueue.Queue('test-queue')
        else:
            q = taskqueue.Queue('ir-upload-queue')

        # q.lease_tasks will return an empty list if no tasks.
        # Empty lists evaluate to False
        t = q.lease_tasks(3600, 1)
        while t:

            self.last_task_complete = self.current_task_complete
            self.current_task_complete = False
            self.current_task = t[0].name
            payload = self.generate_payload_dict(t[0].payload)

            logging.info('***  Processing task ' + self.current_task + '  ***')
            logging.debug(repr(payload))

            with FileParser() as fp:

                try:
                    logging.info('Beginning parse...')
                    result = fp.ParseFile(payload['new_file_name_full'], payload['format'], payload['upload_id'], payload)
                    if payload['name_file_temp'] != None and result == True:
                        fp.ParseFile(payload['new_csu_name_file_name_full'], "name", payload['upload_id'], payload)

                except:
                    logging.error('Unknown error occured!')
                    self.current_task_complete = False
                    # Release the task lease
                    q.modify_task_lease(t[0], 0)
                    self.reset_tables(payload['upload_id'], payload['format'])
                    self.shutdown()
                    raise

                else:
                    self.current_task_complete = True
                    q.delete_tasks_by_name(self.current_task)

            if self.current_task_complete == True:
                # Sleep for 5 seconds, then check for new tasks
                time.sleep(5)
                t = q.lease_tasks(3600, 1)

        self.shutdown()


class StartupHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        logging.info('Starting instance of module batch-processor')

class BatchProcessorHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):

        logging.info('Initial Memory:')
        logging.info('CPU Usage: ' + str(quota.megacycles_to_cpu_seconds(runtime.cpu_usage().total())))
        logging.info('Memory Usage: ' + str(runtime.memory_usage().current()))

        proc = FileParserWrapper()

        def run(arg):
            proc.run_parser()

        def shutdown():
            logging.info('BatchProcessorHandler().get().shutdown()')
            self.response.set_status(200)
            proc.shutdown()

        # Register shutdown hook
        hook = runtime.set_shutdown_hook(shutdown)
        # Start background thread
        tid = background_thread.start_new_background_thread(run, [True])


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/_ah/start', StartupHandler),
    ('/_ah/queue/default', BatchProcessorHandler),
], debug=True)
```

Most of my code is the same. What I did, though, is mapped my `BatchProcessorHandler` to `/_ah/queue/default`, which maps to the default Task Queue. Then, in one of my other scripts, after I add the task to the Pull queue, I create a "dummy" task, give it a `target` of the version/module pair, and assign it to the default Push queue. This ends up calling `BatchProcessorHandler`. Here is that portion of the code:

```
...
other code here
...

    # Start up a batch-processor instance
    logging.info('Starting instance of batch-processor')
    try:
        the_retry_options = taskqueue.TaskRetryOptions(task_retry_limit=1)
        taskqueue.add(target='1.batch-processor', retry_options=the_retry_options)
    except modules.UnexpectedStateError:
        logging.warning('Instance already started!')
    except:
        logging.error('Could not start module!')
        raise
```

`1.batch-processor` is the version/module pair I was talking about. I'm adding an empty task to the queue, and the purpose of that is to basically "ping" the endpoint `/_ah/queue/default`, which starts up `BatchProcessorHandler`.